# How to insert characters after every line in a file?

Tags: scripts

I want to create a script that insert 20 characters following each line in a text file.

Suppose the file contains the following lines:

```
text....
text....
text...
```

I want to obtain:

```
text....
------(20 symbols)
text....
------(20 symbols)
text...
------(20 symbols)
```

How to do this?

Comment: Actually I wanted to obtain after that a modified filed, with the contant shown above. Thanks much

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand. Perhaps you mean you want to modify the file inplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    echo "characters"
done < input > output
```

Where `input` is the source file and `output` is the destination file.

If you want to `input` and `output` to be the standard input and output respectively, then replace `done < input > output` with just `done`.

Answer (score 2):

One way (there are many) is using the `sed` *append* command

```
sed 'a\
Extra twenty characters
' myfile
```

If this is for homework, you should consider what your class is about and what you are supposed to be learning, and select the most appropriate answer based on that

Comment: _... you should consider what your class is about ..._: +1. I though this was a pure-shell question, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please tell me how this will apend text after each line of text file? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: No, that is not homework :) I am getting used to Linux environment

Answer (score 0):

If input file is Hugh then you could use `awk` to perform it faster..

```
awk '{print $0,"\ntype your symbols here "}' input > output
```